# How to correctly display records in Angular JS after deleting from database

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

can you please advice what is wrong with this code? When I click on X, record is correctly deleted from database but no updated table is displayed.

http://michalurban.cz/angular/

Here you can find PHP code from **delete.php**:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM kosmonaut WHERE id=$id";
$delete = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if(!$delete){
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
}else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM kosmonaut";
    $dotaz = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $output = array();

    if(mysqli_num_rows($dotaz) >= 1){
        while($radek = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dotaz)){
           $output[] = $radek;
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Comment: What's the code that performs the AJAX request and generates the table?

Comment: It is code inside anonymous function $scope.smazat = function(id){}.....
Results are then send to rows of table, you can see it with use of developer tools

Comment: It works as expected.